# call wget with some unicode in xml post-file

Tags: xml, unix, unicode, wget

I run the below `wget` command from unix-solaris, for calling a web-service with posting xml file.
The problem is that the xml file contains some Unicode (Hebrew words), and the web service fails.

```
wget http://tws-sub.bbtest.com/sub/swizard.asmx --post-file=NAC.xml \
     --header="Content-Type:text/xml" --output-file=output.txt
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you show us the xml file? And please post the error as well.

Comment: Here is part of the xml file.
Problem in data of <city> - in Hebrew :
 
            <address>
            <str_address_ws>
              <adr_type>M</adr_type>
              <city>ראשון-לציון</city>
              <house_no>55</house_no>
              <street_name>הרצל</street_name>
              <apartment_no>1</apartment_no>
              <city_code>8300</city_code>
              <street_code>0307</street_code>
              <pob>1234</pob>
            </str_address_ws>
          </address>